# How do I keep my AccessibilityService alive

Tags: android, service, accessibilityservice

I hope my AccessibilityService will not be terminated when manually clearing memory with one click.
And I have tried some ways, but all NG.

1.NotificationListener,NG
2.startForeground,NG
3.android:process=":service",NG
4.android:stopWithTask="false",NG